# Dplyr not installing

Tags: r

Took a quick google search and couldn't find any issues like this.

I'm trying to install `dplyr` but it freezes part way through.

```
 install.packages("dplyr")
 Installing package into ‘W:/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
 also installing the dependencies ‘assertthat’, ‘R6’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘magrittr’,
 ‘lazyeval’, ‘DBI’, ‘BH’

 trying URL 
'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/assertthat_0.1.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 44746 bytes (43 KB)
 downloaded 43 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/R6_2.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 271158 bytes (264 KB)
downloaded 264 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/Rcpp_0.12.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3225584 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/magrittr_1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 149394 bytes (145 KB)
downloaded 145 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/lazyeval_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 137792 bytes (134 KB)
downloaded 134 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/DBI_0.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 207812 bytes (202 KB)
downloaded 202 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/BH_1.60.0-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 15529281 bytes (14.8 MB)
downloaded 14.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/dplyr_0.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2393257 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘R6’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘DBI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

After that it just stops and doesn't move on to `BH` or `dplyr`.  It's been about 10 minutes and still says its running but nothing happening.  I deleted them out of the library and tried installing again, as well as another time from a different source.  No luck.  Any idea what's happening?

Comment: I installed dplyr today on a windows PC and had the same issue with it stalling. I was just about to stop it when it started working again.

Comment: Just left it on over lunch and finally finished.  Weird.

Comment: Im having the same struggle. I've installed it on my personal computer just fine and it worked, but for some reason my work machine is not a fan of it. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a little bit of patience is the trick. Give it a good 10 minutes or so and walk away.

If you look at the relative sizes, BH is 5 times larger than the next largest file, and Rccp, its over 25 times as large as the rest of the ones that come before it. So it makes sense that it takes a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

As someone above said patience is the key. It is true. I waited for some 2-3 min In your case it might take more or less but it worked after that so please wait until it's done hope you will find it helpful